# apache2-prefork-dev installation

Tags: rpm, yum, apache2.4

I currently use yum and am trying to install apache2-prefork-dev package by the command line

```
sudo yum install apache2-prefork-dev
```

But i get the response:

No package apache2-prefork-dev available. Is the package under a different name for rpm or centos?

Answer (score 3):

It turned out to be

```
 sudo yum install httpd-devel
```