# prefork.c is not shown in httpd -l

Tags: apache, centos7, preforking

I have CentOS 7 and the version of my apache is 2.4.6.
I typed this command:

```
httpd -l
```

This is the answer:

```
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_so.c
  http_core.c
```

Therefore, I cannot see the prefork.c among these modules. Also, I cannot see the prefork module in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
but the answer of the `httpd -V | grep "Server MPM"` is:

```
Server MPM:     prefork
```

Moreover, the suggestion of these links is not helpful:
[apache2-prefork-dev installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25650727/apache2-prefork-dev-installation)
[Prefork MPM configuration not in httpd.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664056/prefork-mpm-configuration-not-in-httpd-conf)
((It means that installing `httpd-devel` was not helpful, and adding following lines in `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf` did not fix my problem:

```
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so

StartServers           5
ServerLimit            256
MaxRequestWorkers      256
MaxConnectionsPerChild 0
```

))
I want to see prefork.c in the answer of `httpd -l` and also I want to see prefork module in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
what should I do?
Thanks for sharing.

Comment: `httpd -l` only outputs the modules that are compiled in the server. Dynamically loaded modules are not listed. Try `httpd -M` instead and see if it appears there

Comment: I can see this module:  mpm_prefork_module (shared).
However, how can I config this module with my preferred config? I cannot see this module in httpd.conf.       parameters such as :
StartServers           5
ServerLimit            256
MaxRequestWorkers      256
MaxConnectionsPerChild 0

Comment: Thank you for your responses, but I do not know which file I should Include in httpd.conf .I want to see prefork.c in the answer of httpd -l and also I want to see prefork module in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

`httpd -l` only lists the modules that have been added at *compile time* in the server, as static modules.

Other modules can be *loaded dynamically* as DSO (Dynamic Shared Object) by calling them with the `LoadModule` directive in the conf file.
You can list them (along with static ones) using `httpd -M` instead of `httpd -l`. If prefork module appears in the list, it's because it is loaded and at work.

Both methods, static and DSO, work well and you can (and probably should) use DSO without any issue.

Regarding the prefork config, it can be inserted directly in httpd.conf, or (as it seems to be your case) in another file, which is then "merged" in the server config with the `Include` directive in httpd.conf.
You may find the prefork config you search by finding which included file it has been stored into (you should have a `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf` but at worst, opening them one by one should eventually give you some result). And if you really want to, you can cut it from there, and paste it directly into httpd.conf instead.

Finally, if you *really* want to see prefork module appear in static modules list, you will have to manually *configure and compile* apache sources, adding that specific module as static in the process.

You can read more about this on [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html), and, should you decide to go that way, you'll probably find that **this question is better suited for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com) website.**

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I can see the following line in the /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf :
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
but I cannot find prefork config. Where can I find the default values of this madule? Itis not in httpd.conf and 00-mpm.conf. If I add my desired config directly in httpd.con, how can I find out that my config works?

Comment: Try `grep -r -i StartServers /etc/httpd/` command, it should give you a hint to where the directives are. You can then tweak them there. If no results are returned, then you simply can add your prefork configuration directly in httpd.conf, although I'd prefer by far add them in 00-mpm.conf. _if mod-status_ is loaded, you can check the results by connecting to `http://<yourserver.address>/server-status/` after a server restart