# PHP Directives in .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp

I have a sample web site with both `.htaccess` and `.user.ini` files. That’s to allow me to try it on servers where PHP is implemented as a module or as CGI.

In the `.htaccess` file, the following has worked in the past:

```
<IfModule mod_php7>
    #   php settings
</IfModule>
```

I found that if I don’t wrap the settings in a conditional block that Apache complains if it’s not running PHP as a module.

That doesn’t seem to work for me in the current version of XAMPP. PHP is obviously running as a module, because if I comment out the `IFModule` directives it works, and the `.user.ini` file is ignored.

That’s OK for now, but what is the correct directive to limit the settings to a PHP module?

I’m running the latest XAMPP on macOS.

Comment: You can run `httpd -l` to get the list of modules ([reference](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/httpd.html)).

Comment: Sorry, that not may be the right command: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489233/prefork-c-is-not-shown-in-httpd-l

Comment: Maybe you have to current version of php installed, so version 8?